# jQuery validation plugin: hide error messages when entering content

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In many forms I am developing with jQuery validation plugin I have many fields to fill like the following:

```
<p>
  <label>Nome</label>
  <span class="field">
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="smallinput"" value=""/>
  </span>
</p>
```

and these fields are declared as required and if they are empty a message error is correctly shown. After that I would like the error message to hide when the user enters information. However, this does not happen. How can I set this? Moreover I have some fields which should contain email addresses whose rule is

```
email:{
   required: true,
   email: true,
},
```

and it happens that some email addresses are claimed to be not valid while instead they are. Is there a way to fix this?

**SOLUTION**

For those who might be interested, what I have tried is to add a class "req" to span elements which are required and when the user types in something and the value changes and is different from the void string, then an attribute style is added to generated label error, like that:

```
jQuery(".req").on('input',function(){

    if (this.value != "")
        jQuery(this).find("label").attr('style','display:none !important');
});
```

This seems to work fine. Obviously, if the value becomes again void then the red label error message is shown again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the comma at "email: true" ?

Comment: Yes I know it works like that, I just hoped there was a way to tell which email are valid and which are not...anyway, what about hide error messages when content is entered?

Comment: As far as i know the plugin provides that by default. I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Do you mean clear on focusing the input? There's an option that does that http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#focuscleanup

Comment: Cool, I can't try it in this moment 'cause I'm travelling home but I'll let you know. Thanks :)